# css builder for mac like VS2010's

Tags: c#, css, lambda, telerik, builder

I can't believe I can't find this.  At work I use VS2010's CSS Builder tool. It isn't WYSIWYG, really all it does is help one remember the available CSS commands, and their possible values, and stuff it in a selector.

I can't seem to find a tool that does this as a standalone product.  I believe CSS Edit did that, but it is now part of $80 Espresso.

I tried CSS3 Toolkit, which is really nothing more than a button generator, and a waste of my $2.99.

Coda does this as well, but again, I don't feel that this is an $80 tool.

Simple CSS does pretty much exactly what I need, and is free, but it is extremely clunky to use IMHO. You have to export the file every time before you can view changes in browser, no save button. Live preview isn't a requirement, but it bugs me that the one in Simple CSS is broken... it doesn't cascade.

Anyone know of a good simple CSS tool for mac? I am tempted to just code one.  It is just a matter of taking all the available fields, and all options from W3, putting in a form, and spitting out a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go for Eclipse and Netbeans you could argue that these two are more geared towards programming in languages such as Java, they can just as well be used for HTML/CSS/javascript.

Bet you can try Aptana which is built specifically for web developers using the Eclipse engine. It is not only free but, it is quite robust, and it supports Eclipse plugins.

A good article that compares CSS editors (not all free bt a quick guide): http://css-tricks.com/reviews-of-mac-css-editors/

And not to miss here are some free CSS editors: http://speckyboy.com/2008/09/15/7-free-css-editors-which-is-the-best-you-choose/

Comment: I had come across those in Google as well. I may end up calling yours the answer, if nothing else it confirms that I am not missing a hidden gem.

Comment: Thanks for the consolation mate... ;)